# php cant handle transparent png

Tags: debian, php-fpm, apache2

I use php7.1, 7.0 and 7.3 all is php-fpm.

When I try on local machine PNG picture, on website, it is okay with transparent background.
But when I push it on server, there is black blackground not transparent.

Any idea where could be the problem? I have installed `php-imagick`

Comment: That's pretty impossible to answer with the given information. You could start by listing differences between your local machine and the server (versions, variants of software and OS involved), but I guess it boils down to looking at your PHP code. This however would make the question better suited for [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was need of upgrade php-gd. Now it works.